# Add a bottom border and icon to my footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I am working on a responsive footer and I was able to get everything working. The layout is where there is a small issue. I am not able to get the bottom border after each li field and also not able to get the icon at the end. This is what I have done so far. Kindly let me know what I am missing.

---

```css
    @media all and (max-width: 979px) {

    .brand-logos{
     margin: 0 auto !important;
     padding: 10px !important;
    }
    
    footer nav ul{
    
    display:block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    
    footer nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    }
    
    footer nav ul li img{
    
    margin: 20px auto !important;
    width: 70% !important;
    display: block !important;
    
    }
    
    footer .footer-navigation .container-inline-css{
     width: 100% !important;
     padding:10px !important;
     margin:0 !important;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #77777A !important;
    }
    
    footer .footer-navigation .container-inline-css span{
     margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        cursor: pointer !important;
    }
    
    footer .footer-navigation div.container-inline-css ul{
     max-height: 0 !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        padding: 0 20px !important;
    }
    
    footer .footer-navigation div.container-inline-css.active ul{
     max-height: 10000px !important;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="footer-navigation">
 <div class="container-inline-css">
  <span class="koh-nav-section-title footer-link-title-text">
        <span>CONTACT INFO</span>

  </span>
  <ul class="koh-nav-section-items footer-link-items-text">
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          <span class="icon-bg icon-phone"> </span>Call 1-800-STERLING</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="/contact-us" target="_self">
          <span class="icon-bg icon-contact"></span> Contact Us</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="container-inline-css">
  <span class="koh-nav-section-title footer-link-title-text">
        <span>OUR COMPANY</span>

  </span>
  <ul class="koh-nav-section-items footer-link-items-text">
   <li><a href="http://www.annsacks.com/" target="_blank">
          About Us</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="http://www.kallista.com/home.kls" target="_blank">
          E-Newsletter Sign Up</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="http://www.robern.com/home.rbn" target="_blank">
          Careers</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="/press-releases" target="_self">
          Press Room</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="http://www.kohler.com/corporate/index.html" target="_blank">
          Kohler Co.</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="container-inline-css">
  <span class="koh-nav-section-title footer-link-title-text">

        <span>RESOURCES</span>

  </span>
  <ul class="koh-nav-section-items footer-link-items-text">
   <li><a href="/litrature" target="_self">
          Literature</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMMnMReFTMuI9bpoctNGPkw/videos" target="_blank">
          Merchandise</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          FAQs</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          Glossary</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          Tech Documents</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="container-inline-css">
  <span class="koh-nav-section-title footer-link-title-text">
        <span>CUSTOMER CARE</span>

  </span>
  <ul class="koh-nav-section-items footer-link-items-text">
   <li><a href="/cad-symbols" target="_self">
          Track Your Order</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="http://www.inspiracionkohler.com/" target="_blank">
          Care &amp; Cleaning</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          Warranties</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          Videos</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          Product Registration</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="container-inline-css">
  <span class="koh-nav-section-title footer-link-title-text">
        <span>SOCIAL</span>

  </span>
  <ul class="koh-nav-section-items footer-link-items-text">
   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/kohlermexico" target="_blank">
          <span class="icon-bg icon-social-facebook"></span>Facebook</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/kohlerco/?hl=en" target="_blank">
          <span class="icon-bg icon-social-instagram"></span>Instagram</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/kohler" target="_blank">
          <span class="icon-bg icon-social-pinterest"></span>Pinterest</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          <span class="icon-bg icon-social-youtube "></span>YouTube</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="null" target="_blank">
          <span class="icon-bg icon-social-houzz"></span> Houzz</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have all the functionality in place, expect for the bottom border of the li elements and also the arrow icon at the end. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You use the footer tag as your CSS selector, but there is no footer tag in your HTML code.

2) You haven't set any border to your li tags. You can accomplish that by adding  to your css

```
.koh-nav-section-items li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

you should be able to add border to the bottom of each li element. If you want to exclude the last element you can add

```
.koh-nav-section-items:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

a tip: try to avoid using !important

note: If you can provide a codepen link to your app, it would be much easier